# Valid values for Apache Flume Source, channel and Sink type

Tags: flume

In Apache Flume we need to specify configuration details of Source, channel and Sink.
For each we must specify type and other properties depending on type.

Is there a reference page which enlists all types of Source, channel and Sink each. And then corresponding other properties based on type.

And when to use which type. 
Can someone please point me to correct documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

There is excellent documentation of all components on the official website: https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html